# Using several columns of a row as stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have an SQL stored procedure with several parameters, and I want to call it using several columns from (the same) row for some of the parameters. Here's what the current implementation looks like (not including the unused columns / parameters, which exist):

```
DECLARE @id int;
select @id = min( id ) from Table_1;
declare @param1 nvarchar(10), @param2 nvarchar(10);
select  @param1 = param1, @param2 = param2 from Table_1 WHERE id=@id;
EXEC [dbo].otherProc @param1, @param2;
```

This is an improvement over multiple selects, but I can't help wondering if there's a way of doing this without variables (except @id). Selecting directly in the EXEC statement doesn't seem to work (or maybe I don't know the right syntax for it).

Comment: You want table valued types/parameters.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You could change your procedures to accept just the `@id` parameter and perform your selects inside the procedure along with your other code.Oracle allows for a `RowType` which lets you specify a single variable/parameter as a row of a particular table, but afaik, SQL Server does not have this.

Comment: @gmiley for normal stored proc that might be a good idea, but in my case otherProc is CLR (autogenerated from C# code) so even if that worked it would only make the code worse.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri I haven't worked with table-valued parameters, would it involve changing the parameters in the stored proc definition? In my case otherProc is CLR and from what I've seen, passing table-valued parameters to CLR is either impossible or extremely complicated.

Comment: Yes it requires changes to stored proc parameters. Anyway you can pass to proc only constants and variables. You can not have expressions there.

Comment: You could write wrapper procedures that accept a different number and/or type of parameters, that then call the auto-generated procedures you have. This will give you the ability to call your procedures with many parameters using only one or two parameters. I guess the question is,what are you trying to achieve? Are you just wanting to make your code more readable?

Comment: @gmiley yeah, basically I just like minimalist code, and out of curiosity, since I'm new to SQL. If there's no simple solution to this it doesn't really matter. Still a valid question, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could execute a dynamic solution:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) 
SELECT @sql = '
EXECUTE dbo.OtherProc ''' + param1 + ''',''' + param2 + ''';'
FROM Table_1
WHERE id=@id;

EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can change the stored procedure, the only improvement I came up with is this:

```
DECLARE @id int, @param1 nvarchar(10), @param2 nvarchar(10);
select @id = min( id ) from Table_1;

select  TOP 1 @id = id, 
        @param1 = param1, 
        @param2 = param2 
from Table_1 
order by id;
```

this way you populate all parameters in a single select statement.

Comment: My code also populates them all in a single statement. I was hoping to avoid parameters, since I don't do anything with them except pass values through them.

Comment: The code you posted populates the `@Id` first, and then the other parameters. mine populates the `@id` with all the others. again, if you can change the procedure, you can pass only the @id and populate everything else inside the procedure.